# Ldap connection throwing object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ldap

Ldap connection throwing object reference not set to an instance of an object error

I am trying to connect to LDAP to authenticate the user. Here is my code, After setting the connction secure socket layer to true, i am getting exception during connection.connect.

Its is throwing exception object reference not set to an instance of an object, i have created object for connection, but dont know what is going wrong. Anybody help me please?

```
using LdapConnection = Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection;
using LdapException = Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapException;

 var ldapHost = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP_HOST"];
 var ldapPort = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LDAP_PORT"];

 var connection = new LdapConnection {SecureSocketLayer = true};
 connection.Connect(ldapHost, Convert.ToInt32(ldapPort)); // Getting exception here object reference not set to an instance of an object.

 sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append(ldapLocation).Append(userName).Append(",").Append(ldapLocationIndia);
 connection.Bind(LdapConnection.Ldap_V3, sb.ToString(), password);
```

Any help please, thanks in advance.

stacktrace info:

at Novell.Directory.Ldap.Connection.connect(String host, Int32 port, Int32 semaphoreId)
   at Novell.Directory.Ldap.Connection.connect(String host, Int32 port)
   at Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
   at Planner.Controllers.AccountController.isAuthenticated(LoginModel model) in c:\Project\Production Version 2.0\Planner\Planner\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 106
   at Planner.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model) in c:\Project\Production Version 2.0\Planner\Planner\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 44
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()

Comment: Please publish the full StackTrace of the exception

Comment: updated the question with stack trace

Comment: @user1557020: I just noticed you rarely "upvoted" for any helpful answers/comments and I would like to encourage you to do so. You should really give the people that help you some upvotes! It just costs you one click as none of your own points are given away and it is a an easy way to show those people that you respect their hard afford to help you!

Comment: sure dude will do now. Thanks for pointing my mistake

Comment: @user1557020 did you find a solution? i'm facing the same issue with the Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard library.

Answer (score 1):

Are `ldapHost` and `ldapPort` properly set in your config?

The exception thrown by `connection.connect()` is of tpye `LDAPException`, so I assume it doesn't even try to connect.

Comment: its working fine if i remove or comment the SecureSocketLayer = true. so port and host is perfect.

Comment: Did you try `var connection = new LdapConnection(); connection.SecureSocketLayer = true;` ?

Comment: yes. i did, its causing the problem, if i comment the securesocketlayer= true, its working fine. otherwise its throwing object reference error

Comment: I don't understand. Does it work if you separate the object creation and the SSL setting? According to the documentation, you can set `securesocketlayer = true` only after you created the object. See http://bit.ly/1zvRkWv, section 1.5.3.

Comment: after your first comment, i have separated the SSL setting, its not working, if i remove the ssl setting its working, with ssl its throwing obejct reference error.

Comment: Well, then I'm at a loss. You sure your server speaks SSL?

Comment: how to check that please?

Comment: Try to connect with some LDAP browsing software, Apache Directory Studio or sth like it. There you can setup the connection and specify if you want to use SSL. If you can connect and browse your LDAP, it supports SSL.